# Word Ladder solving program broken

Tags: java

I'm trying to make a program to print out a word ladder between any two words in the standard dictionary text file, but it keeps getting stuck on a single word. When I try "angel" and "demon", it's always "vegie".

Here's the code:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Queue;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Stack;
class WordLadder
{
    static ArrayList words=new ArrayList();
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        EasyReader dictFile=new EasyReader("C:\\dict.txt");
        EasyReader input=new EasyReader();
        String o;
        while ((o = dictFile.readWord()) != null)
        {
            words.add(o.toLowerCase());
        }
        System.out.println("What is the starting word?");
        String start=input.readLine();
        System.out.println("What is the ending word?");
        String end=input.readLine();
        if(start.length()!=end.length())
        {
            System.out.println("The words have to be the same length!");
            System.exit(0);
        }
        boolean isfound=false;
        LinkedList q = new LinkedList();
        LinkedList procq = new LinkedList();
        Stack starter=new Stack();
        starter.push(start);
        q.add(starter);
        ArrayList used=new ArrayList();
        used.add(start);
        while(!isfound)
        {
            Stack process=(Stack)q.removeLast();
            System.out.println("finding one-offs for "+process.peek());
            ArrayList oneoffs=findOneOffWords(process.peek().toString(), used);
            System.out.println(oneoffs);
            if(!oneoffs.isEmpty())
            {
                for(int i=0;i<oneoffs.size();i++)
                {
                    Stack toproc=process;
                    System.out.println("processing stack: "+toproc);
                    toproc.add(oneoffs.get(i));
                    while(q.removeFirstOccurrence((Object)toproc))
                    {
                    }
                    boolean isused=false;
                    for (Object temp : used)
                    {
                        if(toproc.peek().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(temp.toString()))
                        {
                            isused=true;
                        }
                    }
                    if(!isused)
                    {
                        q.add(toproc);
                    }
                    used.add(oneoffs.get(i));
                    if(toproc.peek().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(end))
                    {
                        System.out.println("found solution!");
                        while(!toproc.empty())
                        {
                            System.out.println(toproc.pop().toString());
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    public static ArrayList findOneOffWords(String word, ArrayList used)
    {
        ArrayList oneoff=new ArrayList();
        for(int i=0;i<167964;i++)
        {
            if(word.length()==words.get(i).toString().length())
            {
                int counter=0;
                for(int h=0; h<word.length(); h++)
                {
                    if(!word.substring(h,h+1).equalsIgnoreCase(words.get(i).toString().substring(h,h+1)))
                    {
                        counter++;
                    }
                }
                boolean isused=false;
                for (Object temp : used)
                {
                    if(words.get(i).toString().equalsIgnoreCase(temp.toString()))
                    {
                        isused=true;
                    }
                }
                if(counter==1&&isused==false)
                {
                    oneoff.add(words.get(i));
                }
            }
        }
        return oneoff;
    }
}
```

Comment: what did you expect to happen after vegie?

Comment: I expected it to continue iterating through the other possible stacks and eventually get to demon. I've assured it's possible with the given dictionary, it just always seems to try only one path and give up if that one doesn't work.

Comment: By "stuck on vegie", do you mean it prints out "finding one offs for vegie" and then stops? I haven't comprehended the code yet, but i notice nothing seems to be updating isfound ever...

Comment: No, it gets to vegie, prints out "finding one offs for vegie" repeatedly, like it's somehow re-adding itself to the queue.